# Border radius has no effect on changing class

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to change the border radius to the last row of a table.
I can notice by an alert that the class is changing as expected but has no effect apparently.
But for example, if I resize the window, then it takes effect... so weird

To change class I use as follows:

```
 $("#tab-users-team tbody tr:last td").each( function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass("inf-left-corner") ) {
          alert($(this).attr("class")); // <-- check
      $(this).removeClass("inf-left-corner");
      $(this).addClass("inf-left-corner-dis");
          alert($(this).attr("class")); // <-- check OK
    }
  });
```

The styles are simply:

```
.inf-left-corner {
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
}
.inf-left-corner-dis {
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
}
```

The point is, as I said before if the window is reloaded, it takes effect, and if I add `background-color: blue;` it changes the radius to 0 too.
May have an explanation but for me has no sense... any help is really appreciated.

```js
function e() {
  var register =
     "<tr id='user3'>"
   + "<td class='inf-left-corner'>Albert</td>"
    + "<td class='inf-right-corner'>Rumber</td>"
    + "</tr>";
   
  // Remove last
  $("#tab-users-team tbody tr:last-child td").each( function() {
 if ( $(this).hasClass("inf-left-corner") ) {
     $(this).removeClass("inf-left-corner");
     $(this).addClass("inf-left-corner-dis");
   }
    if ( $(this).hasClass("inf-right-corner") ) {
     $(this).removeClass("inf-right-corner");
     $(this).addClass("inf-right-corner-dis");
    }
  });
  $('#tab-users-team tbody').append ( register );
}
```

```css
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #4f90c833;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #4f90c855;
}

.sup-left-corner {
 border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 0px; 
}

.sup-right-corner {
 border-radius: 0px 15px 0px 0px; 
}

.inf-right-corner {
 border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 0px; 
}

.inf-left-corner {
 border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
}


.inf-right-corner-dis {
 border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
}

.inf-left-corner-dis {
 border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<table id="tab-users-team">
    <thead>
      <tr>
     <th class="sup-left-corner">Name</th>
     <th class="sup-right-corner">Provider</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr id="user1">
        <td>Henry</td>
       <td>Groshil</td>
     </tr>
       <tr class="row-us" id="user2">
        <td class="inf-left-corner">Allister
        </td>
       <td class="inf-right-corner">Frisper
       </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="add" onclick="e()" type="button">X</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is HTML ? `tr:last-child`

Comment: To get last element: "#tab-users-team tbody tr:last td"

Comment: @dapdap, :last is not a valid psuedo selector according to w3c. Either use  "#tab-users-team tbody tr").last().find("td") or use #tab-users-team tbody tr:last-child td"

Comment: thanks but using  #tab-users-team tbody tr:last-child td" happens the same. It takes not effect until I reload the window

Comment: "if I resize the window then it takes effect" / "it takes no effect until I reload the window" - which is it?  Have a read of [mcve] and create a working snippet that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @Jayruben `:last` is not a css selector, it's a jquery pseudo selector and perfectly valid (which is why OP gets their "check")

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've provided.  It's not some strange quirk that your specific class names cause something to fail.  It's some *other* part of your HTML and/or CSS that is making it not do what you want/expect.   You'll need to provide more information / scope.  Your code working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/tsgrzevo/

Comment: @freedomn-m this is what I have. An example of what I meant

Comment: Interesting browser bug.

Comment: @epascarello that's also the conclusion I came to.  Also tried with pure-css which should have also worked.  Tried it in IEdge and it doesn't show any background-colors/borders at all - lol.

Comment: @dapap chrome has a number of "wont fix" bugs related to table borders, looks like you've found another one.  Good job providing the working snippet, gave something to work with/demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a rendering bug in chrome. One way to get around it is to use a span inside of the TDs.

```js
function e() {
  var register =
    "<tr>" +
    "<td><span>Alber</span></td>" +
    "<td><span>Rumber</span></td>" +
    "</tr>";

  $('#tab-users-team tbody').append(register);
}
```

```css
tbody tr td span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4f90c855;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td span {
  background-color: #4f90c833;
}

tbody tr:last-child td:first-child span {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
}

tbody tr:last-child td:last-child span {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <table id="tab-users-team">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="sup-left-corner">Name</th>
        <th class="sup-right-corner">Provider</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="user1">
        <td><span>Henry</span></td>
        <td><span>Groshil</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row-us" id="user2">
        <td><span>Allister</span>
        </td>
        <td><span>Frisper</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button id="add" onclick="e()" type="button">X</button>
</body>

</html>
```